# How to cut end of line when reading files?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the contents of a file into an array. The last item in a line is bringing the end of line character with it, which I don't want. Here's what I'm doing:

```
@arr = []
File.open('somefile.txt', 'r') do |file|  
    while (line = file.gets)
        puts "'#{line.split('|')[2]}'"
        @arr << line
    end
end
```

Data in the file looks like this:

```
col1|col2|col3
col1|col2|col3
col1|col2|col3
```

For `col3`, it is including the end of line character. I can tell this from the above `puts`, which outputs:

> 'col3
>   '

I've tried file.gets.chomp but that throws the following error:

> undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

How do I remove the end of line character?

Comment: Try:

if(line.size > 0){
        puts "'#{line.split('|')[2]}'"
        @arr << line
}

Comment: I suggest you write `@arr = []; File.foreach('animals.txt') { |line| @arr << line.chomp }; @arr #=> ["col1|col2|col3", "col1|col2|col3", "col1|col2|col3"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because when the file is read completely, `file.gets` returns `nil`, and calling `.chomp` on that throws the error you mentioned.

You could, however, call `.chomp()` inside the `while` block, where is it guaranteed that `line` is not `nil`.

For example, instead of

```
puts "'#{line.split('|')[2]}'"
```

you could do

```
puts "'#{line.chomp.split('|')[2]}'"
```